# Web Services HTTP usando Java

Tags: java, webservice, http

estoy trabajando con una api rest desarrollada en java para proporcionar servicios rest HTPP.
Para obtener los datos enviados desde el cliente estoy usando tanto @HeaderParam, @QueryParam, @PathParam. Lo que ocurre es que quisiera capturar los datos enviados desde el body de la petición en el cliente como la imagen que adjunto a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para poder ver datos como request y response al momento de llamar a servicios Rest, la opción mas adecuada es habilitar el log en el framework, Asumo que estas trabajando con Spring framework, es necesario mencionar que libreria o framework utilizas . Si asi, dentro de los archivo de propiedad de tu proyecto por ejm application.yml o application.properties debes agregar lo siguiente

```
logging:
  level:
    com.proyecto.service:  DEBUG
```

donde "com.proyecto.service" seria el paquete root de tu proyecto

Comment: Hola :) no estoy usando spring boot, es unicamente java con servlets y lo que queria saber es si existe alguna anotacion tipo @HeaderParam para recibir un objeto de tipo JSON